# Initialize char pointer array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Is it safe to initialize some of the elements in the array like this?

```
const char *str_array[50] = {
    [0] = "str_0",
    [10] = "str_10",
    [24] = "str_24",
    [45] = "str_45",
};
```

Can I rely on the other elements of the array being properly initialized?

Comment: Yes, it is.  All the other slots are automatically NULL. (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.7.9 Initialization, ¶19 _The initialization shall occur in initializer list order, each initializer provided for a
particular subobject overriding any previously listed initializer for the same subobject;
all subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly the same as
objects that have static storage duration._

Comment: Is it safe? Every element not explicitly set, will be `0`, which is the usual value of `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre! If the size of the array is 4K, how can I set all others to NULL and initialize few of them like above. I tried to access uninitialized element and I got (null). So I assume I don't need to set them to NULL.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler. What if I want other elements to set to same default value ? How should I do this?

Comment: @WeatherVane: It's not a matter of the "usual" value. Regardless of how an implementation represents null pointers (which may or may not be all-bits-zero), the elements not explicitly set *will* be set to null pointers.

Comment: it's time to [edit] your question instead of asking other questions in comment. This is not a regular forum, this is a Q&A site.

Comment: _What if I want other elements to set to same default value?_  You have to choose NULL as the default value.  You don't have any other alternatives in standard C, unlike sophisticated modern languages such as, oh, I dunno — let's think of Fortran 66.  There's no way in standard C to repeat an initializer other than by writing it many times.  GCC has an extension that allows you to do that ([designated initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits)).

Comment: @KeithThompson they are set to `0`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Don't make edits that change the meaning of the question if any answers have been posted. (As I write this there are no answers, so it's probably ok to make changes.)

Comment: Sure @Jean-FrançoisFabre. Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: @WeatherVane: They are set to the null pointer. An implementation that doesn't set them to the null pointer is not a conforming C implementation.

Comment: @KeithThompson I would appreciate a citation.

Comment: @KeithThompson I'm not going to edit OP post. I'll let him do it. If someone wanted to answer as-is he'd done that already. of course if there were already an answer, it would be bad to edit.

Comment: @WeatherVane: See Jonathan  Leffler's comment above, and [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.7.9 paragraph 10. It explicitly refers to a null pointer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: I was advising the OP not to edit if there are answers. I tagged you because I was replying to your comment.

Comment: @KeithThompson ok no sweat!

Comment: How should I mark this question as answered or solved?

Comment: @MeRock027 I suggest to edit it to add more information on what should be the default value before someone can properly answer. You may even get upvotes on the Q.

Comment: @KeithThompson and JL thank you for that education.

Comment: @MeRock027: The way to mark a question as solved is to accept an answer. There was no answer yet when you wrote that comment, but there is now. (Since the answer is mine, I'm not going to advise you to accept or upvote it; do so only if you feel it answers your question.)

Comment: @MeRock027: I've taken the liberty of editing your question to clarify the concern I think you're having. Please feel free to revert the edit (or I can do so) if it doesn't accurately reflect what you had in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialization shown in the question is safe, and the elements not specifically initialized with a designated initializer are (in this context) initialized to NULL.  In general, the uninitialized elements are initialized the same as a static variable of the same type would be initialized, which is some variation on the theme of 'zero'.

The relevant section of the C standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) is [§6.7.9 **Initialization**](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9), and specifically ¶19:

> The initialization shall occur in initializer list order, each initializer provided for a particular subobject overriding any previously listed initializer for the same subobject;<sup>151)</sup> all subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.
>
> <sup>151)</sup> Any initializer for the subobject which is overridden and so not used to initialize that subobject might not be evaluated at all.

There was a rejoinder in the comments:

> What if I want other elements to set to same default value?

Unfortunately, you have to choose NULL (in this case; zero in the general case) as the default value. You don't have any other alternatives in standard C (unlike sophisticated modern languages such as, oh, I dunno — let's think of Fortran 66). There's no way in standard C to repeat an initializer other than by writing it many times.

GCC has an extension that allows you to do that (which is documented in the GCC manual in a section with the title [Designated Initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits) that documents both standard behaviour and non-standard behaviour).  Using the GNU extension, you could write:

```
const char *str_array[50] = {
    [1 ... 49] = "empty string",  // GCC extension
    [0] = "str_0",
    [10] = "str_10",
    [24] = "str_24",
    [45] = "str_45",
};
```

Note that it is OK to specify two initializers for a cell (such as 10, 24, 45 — the other is via the repeated initializer); the last one mentioned wins.  Also note the space separating the `...` from the `1` (and `45`); that is crucial because of the 'maximal munch rule' which means that `[1...45]` would be tokenized as `[`, `1.`, `.`, `.45`, `]`, where the floating point numbers are not what's wanted.

Comment: Thanks again Jonathan for addressing my another question! Appreciate it!

Comment: Designated initializers are not a gcc extension; they're standard since C99. The `...` syntax is a gcc extension.

Comment: @KeithThompson — No; it's just the section of the GCC manual where the GCC extension to the standard designated initializer syntax is documented.   Since it has caused you confusion, I've edited the answer to try and make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's quite safe.

See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 6.7.9.

Paragraph 19, discussing initializer lists:

> ... all subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
>   duration.

Paragraph 10:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static
>   or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
>     — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
> - if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;

Comment: Thanks @Keith. I updated the question with answer lol.  Btw thanks for providing reference link. This will definitely help me in learning C.